# Getting Error While Installing Pillow using pip

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-imaging-library

I am Getting this error when i am installing pillow using command.

```
$pip install Pillow
```

and i am running this command in *virtual environment*

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/install_lib.py", line 111, in build
    self.run_command('build_ext')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 337, in run
    self.build_extensions()
  File "setup.py", line 515, in build_extensions
    % (f, f))
ValueError: --enable-jpeg requested but jpeg not found, aborting.
```

Comment: What OS? You need `libjpeg`, if you need help with that I need to know some more details.

You probably also need `zlib`.

Answer (score 1):

you need to install the zlib-devel package in Linux in order to resolve this particular issue.

```
dnf install zlib-devel
```

works for Fedora.

Answer (score 0):

The newly released Python 3.0.0 now requires libjpeg for .jpg (and zlib for .png) by default.

From the [docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.0.x/installation.html#external-libraries):

> - Starting with Pillow 3.0.0, libjpeg is required by default, but may be disabled with the `--disable-jpeg` flag.

See here for how to use [build options](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.0.x/installation.html#build-options), and elsewhere on that page for instructions how to install libraries for different platforms.

Answer (score 0):

For AWS (Red Hat) you need to run the following two commands to get Pillow to install.

```
sudo yum install libjpeg
sudo yum install zlib-devel
```

Also note that you have to uninstall PIL if you are using it in the same environment.